# How I get y_true and y_pred values for loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

How do I get the `y_true` and `y_pred` values for this loss function I wrote :

```
def kullback_leibler_divergence(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = K.clip(y_true, K.epsilon(), 1)
    y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1)
    return K.sum(y_true * K.log(y_true / y_pred), axis=-1)
```

Comment: This is a correct signature for a loss function. Something doesn't work?

Comment: It's give me the error `NameError: name 'y_true' is not defined`

Comment: Please include full code and traceback, errors without context are meaningless

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it helps but, in machine learning
`y_true` refers to the true values, the original labels.
`y_pred` are the predictions of your classifier thus `y_pred = clf.predict(y_true)`
The loss function essentially computes how far the predictions are from the 'true' labels.

Comment: do you can to send me Github username? I want to share you the full code

Answer (score 1):

As I understood your question this might be useful.you can use `from tensorflow.keras import backend as K` to calculate anything using y_true, y_pred as the following example
when you compile, you should add the functions  **to the loss **. then it will provide y_true, y_pred values.

**loss**:*String (name of objective function)*, objective function or tf.keras.losses.Loss instance. See tf.keras.losses. *An objective function* is any callable with the signature loss = fn(y_true, y_pred)

```
# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=kullback_leibler_divergence, metrics=['accuracy'])
```